# "Most Important Const" again

Tags: c++, g++, constants, rule

Came across [THIS](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) post by Herb Sutter "again" and I started thinking why shouldn't the same hold true for const pointer as well .
Here is the test code

```
const char* get()
{
    std::string a("something");
    return a.substr(1, a.size() - 3).c_str();
}

int main()
{
    const char* str = get();
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

std string's `substr` returns a new string object. Compiling with `g++ -Wall` also didn't give me any error. So does this example also shows the prolonged temporary behavior OR I am just lucky here ?

Comment: Yeah I really didnt want to write that..editing it out

Comment: You are *unlucky*. You have undefined behaviour. There is no prolongation of the lifetime of the local object. Also, the code you are showing has no reference equivalent in the GOTW you link to.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You mean temporaries are not prolonged for const pointers, right? Why g++ couldnt put up a warning, I am using fairly recent version of it. Yes, the question is not for reference, its for const pointer

Comment: The only temporary of interest here gets destroyed inside `get`. Do you propose it to be destroyed elsewhere? Where exactly? If so, what should be the rules governing its destruction? Can you make them less all-encompassing than "C++ should get a general purpose garbage collector"?

Comment: At first place I was thinking why not make its scope same as that of the pointer. But then I think its not that straight forward from compiler's perspective. Can you put up that as an answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The rule states:
*"The lifetime of the temporary bound to a **const reference** extends till the lifetime of const."*

There is no reference used in your code example & it is unrelated to the GOTW code sample.Your code simply gives you **undefined behavior**. Depending on how you look at it, you may consider yourself lucky/unlucky that it works.

**Important Note:**
References are not pointers!!

Comment: Whether or not the reference is const actually doesn't matter. If you bind a temporary to a non-const (rvalue) reference, the lifetime is also extended. See `[class.temporary]/5`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Never said this question is related to that GOTW post :)

Answer (score 0):

No, a pointer to `const` does *not* prolong the lifetime of a temporary.

Only when binding a temporary to a *reference* to `const` will the lifetime be lengthened to the lifetime of the reference itself.

```
{
    Foo factory();

    const Foo& fooRef = factory();
    const Foo* fooPtr = &factory();

    fooRef.doSomething(); // OK
    fooPtr.doSomething(); // UB, dangling pointer.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine, that std::string is simple something like this:

```
class string {
    const char *str_;
    string(const char *str) {
        str_ = new char[strlen(str)];
        strcpy(str_, str);
    }
    ~string() {
        delete[] str;
    }
    const char *c_str() {
        return str_;
    }
}
```

so, after returning from get() string will be destroyed and you will have a pointer to garbage.  You can easily detect this error with valgrind or similar tool.